# Using Vite to compile Angular with Nx in versions 15/14 before official support in v16?

Tags: angular, vite, nrwl-nx

Can I use Vite instead of Webpack to compile my Angular application with Nx in versions 15 or 14, even though it's officially supported by Angular only in version 16?